# Elastic BeansTalk server: Facebook signup and signin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on asp.net mvc web application and implemented Graph API. Facebook signup and signin are working fine when working with localhost. After deployment on AWS Elastic BeansTalk server, it is not working just retirning error

```
A Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Thanks